# Rails root path with locale but without query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I want to apply i18n to the root path of my application. The [Rails i18n guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) suggests:

> Of course, you need to take special care of the root URL (usually "homepage" or "dashboard") of your application. A URL like http://localhost:3001/nl will not work automatically, because the root to: "books#index" declaration in your routes.rb doesn't take locale into account. (And rightly so: there's only one "root" URL.)
>
> You would probably need to map URLs like these:

```
# config/routes.rb
get "/:locale" => "dashboard#index"
```

However this configuration doesn't work nicely when using URL helpers. The following produces a URL with a query string:

```
root_path(locale: "fr") # => "/?locale=fr"
```

But I want to produce a URL with the locale in the path:

```
/fr
```

Answer (score 3):

By defining a `root` and `locale_root`:

```
# config/routes.rb
root to: "dashboard#index"

scope "/:locale" do
  get "/", to: "dashboard#index", as: :locale_root
end
```

You can then use the `locale_root_path` and `locale_root_url` helpers:

```
locale_root_path(locale: "fr") # => "/fr"
```